# How parse fetch text from html tags in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, html-parsing

I have a html as text in **nodejs** as follow:

```js
var htmlText = `<div class="X7NTVe">
        <a class="tHmfQe" href="/link1">
            <div class="am3QBf">
                <div>
                    <span>
                        <div class="BNeawe deIvCb AP7Wnd">
                            <span dir="rtl">My First Text</span>
                        </div>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>
        <div class="HBTM6d XS7yGd">
            <a href="/anotherLink1">
                <div class="BNeawe mAdjQc uEec3 AP7Wnd">&gt;</div>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="x54gtf"></div>
    <div class="X7NTVe">
        <a class="tHmfQe" href="/link2">
            <div class="am3QBf">
                <div>
                    <span>
                        <div class="BNeawe deIvCb AP7Wnd">
                            <span dir="rtl">My Second Text</span>
                        </div>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>
        <div class="HBTM6d XS7yGd">
            <a href="/anotherLink2">
                <div class="BNeawe mAdjQc uEec3 AP7Wnd">&gt;</div>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="x54gtf"></div>`
```

Now I Want to fetch text form it as array. In abow example it must return `My First Text` and `My Second Text` . How can I do it?

**Note**: I want to do it in nodejs note in javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With cheerio:

```
let $ = cheerio.load(html)
let strings = $('div[class="BNeawe deIvCb AP7Wnd"]>span[dir]')
              .get().map(span => $(span).text())
```

Comment: Can you change select element from `<div class="BNeawe deIvCb AP7Wnd">`?

Comment: it's just css. So: `div[class="BNeawe deIvCb AP7Wnd"]`

Answer (score 1):

## method#1

replace all tags with regex `/<[^>]*>/g`.

## method#2

parse html with [jsdom](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsdom), and access html node via js document api.

> method#2 is much more flexible.

Comment: For method#1 I have another text, and for method#2 how do it?

Comment: you can create a virtual document environment via `jsdom` package, take a look at [jsdom docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsdom#basic-usage).